# Python RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of a tuple

Tags: python, recursion

I have tried looking at a few other solutions to similar problems, but I'm still having an issue. Here is my code:

```
def nearest_neighbor(cities_tups, temp_dist, best_tour):
   if best_tour == []:
       best_tour.insert(0, cities_tups[0])
       print(best_tour)
       nearest_neighbor(cities_tups, temp_dist, best_tour)
   else:
        last_point = best_tour[len(best_tour) - 1]
        best_next = (math.inf, math.inf)
        for l in cities_tups:
            print('Last Point was:', last_point)
            print('This Point is:', l)
            if((distance((last_point[0],last_point[1]), (l[0],l[1]))) < (distance((last_point[0],last_point[1]), (best_next[0],best_next[1])))):
                print('new best detected')
                distance_to_add = distance((last_point[0],last_point[1]), (l[0],l[1]))
                best_next = l
        best_tour.insert(len(best_tour),best_next)
        temp_dist += distance_to_add
        print('best tour:', best_tour)
        print('temp dist:', temp_dist)
        nearest_neighbor(cities_tups, temp_dist, best_tour)
```

I am trying to use a nearest neighbor algorithm to find the "best" path between points. The points are being stored in 'cities_tups' which is a tuple containing tuples with x and y coordinates. The code will run for several iterations before the RecursionError is thrown. Am I simply running out of memory or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Under every possible circumstance, the function recursively calls itself.  How were you imagining that this could ever end?

Comment: @jasonharper This can probably be added as the answer

Comment: This is definitely the fix. Thank you!